# MQ usage with multiple clients and non-dequeueing read

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm having the following task: I have two clients hung on the same queue and both are able to consume all kinds of messages. The desired functionality is that a client reads the message from the queue without committing it and only commits once it finishes processing. During that the other client should not be able to process the message (non-dequeueing, blocking read = NDBR). 
Practical example:

Messages put on queue, Msg1, and Msg2. Desired functionality: 
Client1 NDBR's Msg 1->Queue content (Msg1-blocked,Msg2)->Client 2 NDBR's Msg2->Queue content(Msg1-blocked,Msg2-blocked)->Client 1 finishes commits Msg1->Queue content(Msg2 - blocked)->Client 2 finishes processing, commits Msg2-> Queue empty.

Is such a solution possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - standard stuff.  It is documented in the manual.  Go look up syncpoint and Commit/Backout.